# How to achieve long lived login session with Oauth2 and javascript client(Spring Oauth2 + Angularjs)

Tags: spring, angularjs, oauth, spring-security, spring-security-oauth2

I've a spring backend with **Spring OAuth2** and **Angular** client.

What is the proper way to achieve **long lived logins** which is still arguably **secure**.

I guess I can use **password flow** and *refresh tokens*, but this doesn't seem any safer than using long lived *access tokens* with **implicit flow** for browser clients. I think I can use:

- *Redirects* - which will interfere with whatever user was doing
- *Popups* - which will get blocked without user interaction

on the client level. But is there any better approach?

P.S: Cloudfoundry's new UI seems to have achieved exactly what I want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solution to me was to use hidden iframes with implicit grant.

Answer (score 2):

The auth code flow is always superior (more secure and less chance of leaking user cerdentials). If you are writing a browser-hosted client contacting the OAuth2 service directly then unfortunately you won't be able to get hold of the access token from the auth code flow. For that reason I think I would prefer to use access tokens between machine (non-browser) clients, and standard cookie-based authentication between the browser and the front end server. You can still use OAuth2 on the front end server to do the authentication (I'm pretty sure that's what the CloudFoundry server is doing) if you expose a /me or /user_info type endpoint.

Or if you really need to get the access token in your client (I guess there are libraries for dealing with it), you can use password or implicit grant. Implicit is strongly preferred on security grounds (since the user only types his password into the auth server authentication UI), but in both cases you need to take care to segregate your client data so the (unauthenticated) clients don't get access to anything they shouldn't.

Comment: Thanks Dave, you are very generous with your time. What do you mean by  "if I really need to get the access token"? I eventually need access tokens to access my REST backend, no? Also by standard cookie-based authentication do you mean it as a replacement for oauth2 or just for the authentication part?

Comment: Also I would very much appreciate if you give a quick opinion http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24925302/spring-oauth-password-grant-with-fb-login on this related question. I'm just trying to see if password grant could an option if I want FB login to be involved.

Comment: I don't think you necessarily *do* need an access token to access a server from a JavaScript client (all you need is to be authenticated). Admittedly I know next to nothing about javascript libraries, so I don't know what angular provides, but the browser already has a contract to send cookies back to the origin, so why not use them?

Comment: Ok I see what you mean. But if my app tends to grow big, therefore separate authorization & resource servers, then only approach is access tokens, right?

Comment: Good point, my bad. I guess that's why implicit grants exist. You can use a refresh token I believe (even if it's not in the spec). I didn't really understand the original question, I must admit. What are your concerns about implicit grants?

Comment: Only concern is its bad user experience when token expires. At that point auth login would still be alive(remember_me). So only option I see is either redirect or popup & both of them has limitations. If I could get a refresh_token with implicit that would be very good. Thats why I was interested in password grant(but then fb login problem). How can I return refresh_token with implicit grant from Spring Oauth? If you can give me direction, I'm comfortable extending spring classes.

Comment: The UX doesn't have to be bad if you control the auth server and there is a long-lived session on it (you can just grant a new token without approval). `UserApprovalHandler` is the relevant extension point and I believe there is already support for auto-approval with simple yes/no logic based on the client id.