# Spring Oauth password grant with FB login

Tags: spring, angularjs, oauth, spring-security, spring-security-oauth2

I've a Spring backend with **Spring OAuth2** and **Angularjs** client.

Plain username/password **password grant**  is no brainer. But what happens when I want the user also to be able to login with another oauth provider such as FB.

I imagine the following flow:

1. First retrieve FB access token from the angular client.
2. Post that token *somehow* as a *password grant request* to the spring endpoint
3. From backend fetch userId using the token from FB.
4. Find user with same fb userId. If found create securityContext for the user.

I assume this should be possible if I could tweak Spring Oauth a little. What classes should I look for extending and configuring?

Comment: As discussed a bit [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24901302/how-to-achieve-long-lived-login-session-with-oauth2-and-javascript-clientspring/24913740?noredirect=1#comment38730179_24913740), I don't necessarily think password grant is a good idea. And I don't know enough about angular to know how it would get a FB token, but I'm not sure why it needs to (your server can handle that as a FB client app). Can you explain your proposed flow a bit?

Comment: I liked the refresh_token from password grant. But you are right, password grant is risky as refresh token can be easily stolen from the browser. So I will drop the idea, thanks.